# Was This Character Anyone Significant?

Tags: marvel, character-identification, new-mutants

Karma's Marvel Wiki has the following segment in the Trivia section:

> Karma is a known lesbian. Although her sexual orientation had been mentioned before, she was never explicitly shown with another woman until Uncanny X-Men #508.

It is accompanied by the following picture:

[image]

Is this anyone significant or just a one-off character?

Comment: I don't believe she's anyone other than *"Sexy woman that Karma was in bed with to demonstrate that she's a lesbian"*

Comment: Following the reference link to that image leads to [Uncanny X-Men Vol 1 508](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Uncanny_X-Men_Vol_1_508) where she is only identified as *'Karma's girlfriend'*.

Comment: @Jeeped - If I had a penny for every omission/error in the Marvel wiki, I'd have a lot of pennies

Comment: I've messaged the writer, editor and editor-in-chief of that comic to see if they have a name for us. I strongly suspect that if they respond, it'll be to tell us that she was a random hookup

Comment: Damn, way to go the extra mile. How did you message them, just through Twitter or something?

Comment: @Gothamite24 - Twitter and private email; https://twitter.com/Answerguesser40/status/1208369403470987264

Comment: We're now more than a hundred issues further on and she's not made another appearance. I think we can be reasonably sure that she was indeed just some random hookup